# USB cables keep damaging - what can cause this?

Tags: usb, cable

Over the course of 12 months, I have had three USB cables fail. Details:

- The cables belonged to different devices: two belonged to an external hard drive, one to a digital watch
- They varied in age (many years; 1 year; few months old) and origin (one was bought individually, the other two came with the devices, which are two different brands)
- The general problem seems to be with file transfers; the charging capacity is seemingly unaffected
- I am getting errors such as "Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?" in dmesg. Sometimes the device mounts but then unmounts again in a matter of seconds. When I try the cables on different machines, they don't work either so it's not a problem of my laptop. When I try a different cable, the HD/watch works again, so it's not a problem of the connecting device.
- Three different USB cables failing in such a short time seems too much of a coincidence and I am therefore suspecting it is something environmental

My question: is there something environmental that can damage a USB cable? What can I look for? Physically, they look fine. They are stored in a box with other things when not in use. One thought: I have a headset that has magnets in them to clamp them together. Could that cause this kind of damage??

Comment: *I have a headset that has magnets in them to clamp them together. Could that cause this kind of damage??* NO! Look for **physical** damage in the cables.

Comment: How do you disconnect a USB device?  Yank on the cable?  Even though cable/wire resembles rope/string, electrical wire cannot handle stretching and physical abuse (whether during use or in storage).  The more flexible the cable means more delicate copper wires within.

Comment: Buy and use "Braided" USB cables - "USB cables that are braided are more durable in most cases. The cord will not kink as easily. ... In addition to preventing fraying and tearing due to everyday use, the woven exterior of the cable also makes it durable under extreme conditions."

Comment: Thanks for the comments. But I have been careful with the cables and I have never yanked them or anything. I understand I can buy more robust cables but am worries that there is another factor impacting my cables given the three that failed recently. Is there no other external factor that might cause this?

Comment: `Is there no other external factor that might cause this?` .. sure :)  A cat!  but as far as the hardware goes, not likely.  Is this happening on all ports or just one?  I guess it is *possible* that a port with a jagged connector *could* damage a connector on a cable, but I have never seen it.

Comment: 1. One device I've used had a badly-made USB connector, capable of damaging cables plugged and unplugged a few times.  2. USB-C can handle very high power, able to destroy a poorly-made cable. 3. A ground-loop between two devices plugged into mains outlets, sharing a cable, such as PC and printer, could destroy a cable -- that also indicates a shock hazard.